# Required value not required when editing properties

Tags: harmon.ie

Here is the scenario:

- The Sharepoint library has a column "X" that is not required.
- Documents are uploaded to this library with colum "X" empty. No problem.
- Column "X" is changed to make it a required value.
- Now, when I edit the property "Y" of a document, I can save it with Harmon.ie without being asked for the required value "X". The normal Sharepoint behaviour would require the value "X" before being able to save it. Why would Harmon.ie let me save it without required values?

I'm using Harmon.ie 5.4.0.9708 on Sharepoint 2013 (on-premise). FYI, Harmon.ie requires the required value for new documents. But not for existing ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue but it only occurs to existing document.
You will get the correct behavior when uploading any other new document.

---- Jean

Comment: Do you Know if this known by Harmon.ie developers?

Comment: I am from Harmon.ie. I hence confirm this is a well-known issue. You will get the correct behavior when uploading any other new document.

Comment: I know! I reported the issue for existing document... Looking forward for a fix in a future release. Thanks.